# react app building fail for deployment in netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify

try to deploy my react app through the netlify but it fails in building process with the following prompt. I have no clue to resolve this issue.

```
12:31:28 AM: Netlify Build                                                 
12:31:28 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: ❯ Version
12:31:28 AM:   @netlify/build 29.11.5
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: ❯ Flags
12:31:28 AM:   baseRelDir: true
12:31:28 AM:   buildId: 646725b7e64ca65254cf9c03
12:31:28 AM:   deployId: 646725b7e64ca65254cf9c05
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: ❯ Current directory
12:31:28 AM:   /opt/build/repo
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: ❯ Config file
12:31:28 AM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: ❯ Context
12:31:28 AM:   production
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: Build command from Netlify app                                
12:31:28 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:31:28 AM: ​
12:31:28 AM: $ npm run build
12:31:29 AM: > takumi-test@0.1.0 build
12:31:29 AM: > react-scripts build
12:31:30 AM: Creating an optimized production build...
12:31:35 AM: Failed to compile.
12:31:35 AM: 
12:31:35 AM: HookWebpackError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
12:31:35 AM: -- inner error --
12:31:35 AM: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'e')
12:31:35 AM: Generated code for /opt/build/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/opt/build/repo/src/App.css
12:31:35 AM:  1 | __webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
12:31:35 AM:  2 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__("/opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[4]!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js");
12:31:35 AM:  3 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
12:31:35 AM:  4 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__("/opt/build/repo/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[4]!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!/opt/build/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js");
12:31:35 AM:  5 | /* harmony import */ var _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
12:31:35 AM:  6 | // Imports
12:31:35 AM:  7 |
12:31:35 AM:  8 |
12:31:35 AM:  9 | var ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___ = _node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_api_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default()((_node_modules_css_loader_dist_runtime_sourceMaps_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()));
12:31:35 AM: 10 | // Module
12:31:35 AM: 11 | ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.push([module.id, ".App {\n  text-align: center;\n}\n\n.App-logo {\n  height: 40vmin;\n  pointer-events: none;\n}\n\n@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {\n  .App-logo {\n    -webkit-animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;\n            animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;\n  }\n}\n\n.App-header {\n  background-color: #282c34;\n  min-height: 100vh;\n  display: flex;\n  flex-direction: column;\n  align-items: center;\n  justify-content: center;\n  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);\n  color: white;\n}\n\n.App-link {\n  color: #61dafb;\n}\n\n@-webkit-keyframes App-logo-spin {\n  from {\n    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);\n            transform: rotate(0deg);\n  }\n  to {\n    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);\n            transform: rotate(360deg);\n  }\n}\n\n@keyframes App-logo-spin {\n  from {\n    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);\n            transform: rotate(0deg);\n  }\n  to {\n    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);\n            transform: rotate(360deg);\n  }\n}\n", "",{"version":3,"sources":["webpack://./src/App.css"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;EACE,kBAAkB;AACpB;;AAEA;EACE,cAAc;EACd,oBAAoB;AACtB;;AAEA;EACE;IACE,oDAA4C;YAA5C,4CAA4C;EAC9C;AACF;;AAEA;EACE,yBAAyB;EACzB,iBAAiB;EACjB,aAAa;EACb,sBAAsB;EACtB,mBAAmB;EACnB,uBAAuB;EACvB,6BAA6B;EAC7B,YAAY;AACd;;AAEA;EACE,cAAc;AAChB;;AAEA;EACE;IACE,+BAAuB;YAAvB,uBAAuB;EACzB;EACA;IACE,iCAAyB;YAAzB,yBAAyB;EAC3B;AACF;;AAPA;EACE;IACE,+BAAuB;YAAvB,uBAAuB;EACzB;EACA;IACE,iCAAyB;YAAzB,yBAAyB;EAC3B;AACF","sourcesContent":[".App {\n  text-align: center;\n}\n\n.App-logo {\n  height: 40vmin;\n  pointer-events: none;\n}\n\n@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {\n  .App-logo {\n    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;\n  }\n}\n\n.App-header {\n  background-color: #282c34;\n  min-height: 100vh;\n  display: flex;\n  flex-direction: column;\n  align-items: center;\n  justify-content: center;\n  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);\n  color: white;\n}\n\n.App-link {\n  color: #61dafb;\n}\n\n@keyframes App-logo-spin {\n  from {\n    transform: rotate(0deg);\n  }\n  to {\n    transform: rotate(360deg);\n  }\n}\n"],"sourceRoot":""}]);
12:31:35 AM: 12 | // Exports
12:31:35 AM: 13 | ___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.locals = {};
12:31:35 AM: 14 | /* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__.d.e.f.a.u.l.t = (___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___);
12:31:35 AM: 15 |
12:31:35 AM: ​
12:31:35 AM: "build.command" failed                                        
12:31:35 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:31:35 AM: ​
12:31:35 AM:   Error message
12:31:35 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
12:31:35 AM: ​
12:31:35 AM:   Error location
12:31:35 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:31:35 AM:   npm run build
12:31:35 AM: ​
12:31:35 AM:   Resolved config
12:31:35 AM:   build:
12:31:35 AM:     command: npm run build
12:31:35 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:31:35 AM:     environment:
12:31:37 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
12:31:35 AM:       - NPM_FLAGS
12:31:35 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
12:31:35 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
12:31:37 AM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:31:37 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:31:37 AM: Finished processing build request in 29.85s
```

I tried to change the build comment in the build setting from "npm run build" to "CI= npm run build", "CI= '' npm run build", and add the environment variable "CI=true" but none of that worked.

Comment: The issue is resolved as I leave the build command as default, 'npm run build' adding an environment variable 'NODE_VERSION = 16.0'. This worked for me!!